# How to add two different components on click of each other in react-native

Tags: typescript, react-hooks, react-native, react-native-ios

I have a component `StatusBoxComponent`, which has two status's: `Break-In` and `Break-out`,

So Initially, `Break-In` box will be seen on opening this screen.

Now what I wanted is that, as I press `Break-in` box, immediately below `Break-out` box should come, and on this `Break-out` box, I again wanted to press this, so that `Break-in` box comes below this. And this process should go on.

```
const AttendanceScreen = (props: any) => {

    const [inState, setInState] = useState([<View />]);
    
    const breakOutClick = () => {
        setInState([
            ...inState,
            <>
                <StatusBoxComponent
                    status={'Break-In'}
                    breakIn={breakInClick}      // Point 3
                />
                {inState}
            </>,
        ]);
    };

    const breakInClick = () => {
        setInState([
            ...inState,
            <>
                <StatusBoxComponent
                    status={'Break-Out'}
                    breakIn={breakOutClick}      // Point 2
                />
                {inState}
            </>,
        ]);
    };

    return (
        <>
            <StatusBoxComponent
                status={'Break-In'}
                breakIn={breakInClick}      // Point 1
            />
            {inState}
        </>
    );
};
```

But, what's happening is, when initially I press `break-in`, one `break-out` box is coming, but when I click on this `break-out`, then instead of adding new box below, it is replacing the current box. And when clicked on the initial `break-in` box, then more than 1 `break-in` boxes are getting added below.

I don't know where in my logic am I going wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Storing components inside state is generally a bad idea, when you can manage your state with serializable values.

```
const AttendanceScreen = (props: any) => {

    const [statuses, setStatuses] = useState(['Break-In']);

    
    
    const breakOutClick = () => {
        setStatuses([
            ...statuses,
            'Break-In',
        ]);
    };

    const breakInClick = () => {
        setStatuses([
            ...statuses,
            'Break-Out',
        ]);
    };

    return (
        <>
            {statuses.map((status, index) => (
                 <StatusBoxComponent
                     key={index}
                     status={status}
                     breakIn={breakInClick}      // Point 1
                 />
            )}
        </>
    );
};
```

Comment: `setInState([ ...inState, 'Break-Out',]);` getting error here: `Type 'string | Element' is not assignable to type 'Element'.
  Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'Element'.`

Comment: @pratteekshaurya i've updated code. `inState` => `statuses`